# Looking for examples and projects with socket.io

Tags: socket.io

Where can I find code-examples for socket.io?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the *Projects using Socket.IO* section here on the [Socket.IO wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Projects-using-Socket.IO)?  There are several resources there.  There's also a great example tutorial [here](http://davidwalsh.name/websocket) by Dave Walsh, and here's a [chatroom example](http://till.klampaeckel.de/blog/archives/133-node.js-socket.io-fun.html).

Answer (score 3):

I would play around with balloons.io.  It is a pretty full featured chat app, that uses socket.io, node.js and redis.

http://balloons.io/

The project is open-source on github

https://github.com/gravityonmars/Balloons.IO

I have created a brand new chat piece of functionality for our website using many of the characteristics of this project.  I would strongly recommend downloading it and getting it running on your localhost.